# Time taken to reflect the custom dimension changes in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to use Google-analytics-API.
In it, I require to fetch the user id of the respective users.
For that I have created the custom dimension (userId) -> `customUser:userId`

But the response doesn't contain any value it is empty for it though if I try with any other standard dimension I am getting the values for it.

Is there any time period after which the changes will be reflected for custom dimensions?

Requests

```
{
  :property=>"properties/property_id",
  :dimensions=>[{:name=>"customUser:userId", :dimension_expression=>nil}],
  :metrics=>[{:name=>"activeUsers", :expression=>"", :invisible=>false}],
  :date_ranges=>[{:start_date=>"yesterday", :end_date=>"today", :name=>"date"}],
  :dimension_filter=>nil,
  :metric_filter=>nil,
  :currency_code=>"",
  :cohort_spec=>nil,
  :keep_empty_rows=>false,
  :return_property_quota=>false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it takes 48 hours to `GA4` to be updated with the new custom information and You will see a value of (not set) for a custom dimension in the first 48 hours.
Please have a look at the documentation [Create custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en)

[image]

Comment: But when we try to hit the data with a dimension of custom and other standard dimension it doesn't return any value.
But if we provide only standard ones we are getting the exact data.
So my doubt is the value in case of custom dimension should be (not set) or null and others values should be there?

Comment: if you are setting your custom dimensions correctly, then only that custom dimension before 48 hours should be "not set" and for the others you should see the value